# How is transaction defined and how is Governor limit applied in Salesforce SDK?

Tags: soql, governorlimits, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, transaction

I am creating an app with iOS using Salesforce SDK. How is transaction defined, and how is governor limit applied in this context?

For example, I have an a.swift file where I am throwing API requests like below.

```
class a {
    func method1() {
        // throw soql API request -> this returns 9999 rows of records
    }
        
    func method2() {
        // throw soql API request -> this returns 2 rows of records
    }
}
```

According to salesforce, I can throw 200 soqls and retrieve 10k rows of records per transaction.
Does it mean in my a.swift file, I will get an error? Not quite sure, how is transactions is defined in this context, and where the governor limit is applied here?

Answer (score 1):

[Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) do not apply to SOQL/SOSL calls made by any API; these limits only apply to Apex code that is running for some reason. There is a general [API Request Limits and Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) document you should refer to instead.

Given you don't violate the number of API calls per day, each query can retrieve millions of records per SOQL call, or [2,000 per SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm). SOQL calls will be [batched](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm) in groups of 200-2,000, defaulting to 2,000 per page.

You should try to optimize your code to take advantage of [Batch and Composite Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/ios_rest_apis_batch_composite.htm) to minimize your API usage, which will be the most important limiter of how many records you can handle per day.

In the most literal sense, you would say that each method performed one "transaction," but that is merely semantics until you start executing Apex code, either by DML or by Apex REST calls.